# PHP mail() sends header with dedicated server domain

Tags: php, ubuntu

When I send mail via PHP's mail() it sends the wrong header information...

```
$to      = 'mypersonal@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello, hi :)';
$headers = 'From: Support <support@site.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: From: support@site.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

in my gmail it shows

> Support via mydedicatedserver.dediprovider.com

How can I configure PHP mail() to send my domain name?

Answer (score 1):

mail() **is** already sending your domain name.

Gmail sometimes displays that message when Google is not familiar with your server and the hostname of your server does not match the domain name you're sending e-mail from. It's an anti-spam/anti-phishing measure.

Add proper SPF records to your domain. If the server is under your control, try changing its hostname to something that includes your domain name, like `server1.site.com`. Follow all other advice listed in the link below. Even then, there is no guarantee that Gmail will drop the message right away. In my experience, that message goes away after a while when Google becomes familiar with e-mails from your server and decides that none of them are spam. But Google seems reluctant to disclose exactly what is required, probably because they don't want spammers to get too clever.

See: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1311182

Also, the `Reply-To: From:` header is wrong.

Comment: I updated my SPF records and changed the header with no luck yet. I'll keep sending some pretty mail and hope gmail sends me some love :) thanks for the help.